# Why is my response body null, status 200?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to get response body from this url:http:"//192.168.0.220:8000/records/?account_id=2"

In android studio i get status 200 but body is always null. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Response in postman looks like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "account_id": 2,
            "title": "ez",
            "datetime": "2021-03-21T00:00:00",
            "description": "ez2",
            "image": null,
            "recording": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "account_id": 2,
            "title": "ez",
            "datetime": "2021-03-21T00:00:00",
            "description": "ez2",
            "image": null,
            "recording": null
        },
....
```

Response in android studio:

```
I/System.out: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.220:8000/records/?account_id=2}
    Item(id=null, account_id=null, title=null, datetime=null, image=null, recording=null)
```

Interface:

```
interface Gett {
    @GET("?account_id=2")
    fun getRecord(): Call<Record.Item>
}
```

Class:

```
class Record {
    data class Item(
        val id: String,
        val account_id: String,
        val title: String,
        val datetime: String,
        val image: String,
        val recording: String
    )
}
```

MainActivity:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.220:8000/records/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()


val service = retrofit.create(Gett::class.java)
            val call = service.getRecord()

call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<Record.Item> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Record.Item>, response: Response<Record.Item>) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        println(response)
                        println(response.body()!!)
                    }
                }
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Record.Item>, t: Throwable) {
                    println("fail")
                }
            })
```

Comment: `fun getRecord(): Response<Record.Item>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be this

```
interface Gett {
    @GET("?account_id=2")
    fun getRecord(): Call<Record.Item> <----
}
```

So, change your model

```
data class Record (
    val result: List<Item>
)

data class Item(
        val id: String,
        val account_id: String,
        val title: String,
        val datetime: String,
        val image: String,
        val recording: String
    )
```

As I can see your JSON has an array of your `Item` so change it to.

```
interface Gett {
    @GET("?account_id=2")
    fun getRecord(): Call<Record>
}
```

Thanks, @Kunn for pointing out JSONObject.

Comment: The response is not a List. It's a JsonObject.